# How to remove + using regex in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

How can one use regex to remove `+` signs in strings.

I am sure there is a simple solution but I couldn't find it. Here is a toy example.

```
X            Y

mouse+       8 
elephant+    9
wolf         5
```

Attempted many variations of gsub but with no success.

```
DF$X <- gsub(DF$X, pattern = "\+", replacement = "")
```

Output should look like this

```
X            Y

mouse        8 
elephant     9
wolf         5
```

Comment: `DF$X <- gsub(DF$X, pattern = "+", replacement = "",fixed=T)`

Comment: Very quick, thank you. Knew it would be a simple fix.

Comment: The `"+"` symbol has special meaning in regular expression, so if you need the exact "+" symbol, you have to use an escape character, i.e. `"\\+"`(double backslash) or set `fixed = T`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do

```
library(stringr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(X = str_replace_all(X, "(\\+)", ""))
#         X  Y
# 1    mouse 8
# 2 elephant 9
# 3     wolf 5
```

Comment: For supplement, `str_replace_all(string, pattern, "")` is equivalent to `str_remove_all(string, pattern)`

Comment: @DarrenTsai It is a good point. Thanks for your helpful information.